# I'm able to get the data in my js file but not in my .vue file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, promise, fetch-api

I'm able to use fetch api (wanted to do the fetch api rather than axios) and call out my local api and console.log the data from my api.js file -

```
 export default {
     async getData(){
         await fetch(url+"campground")
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data) // [{id:123,name:"Shimla"},{id:124,name:"Manali"}]
            return data
        })
    }
 }
```

The issue arises when I try to do it on my Catalogue.vue file.

```
<script>
      import api from '../api';
      export default {
        name: 'Catalogue',
        data() {
          return {
            camps: null
          }
        },
        methods: {
          
        },
        created() {
           this.camps = api.getData() 
           console.log(this.camps) //Promise { <state>: "pending" }
        },
      }
    
    </script>
```

The result that I get is usually

> Promise { : "pending" }

How can I proceed from here? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from getData and because fetch is async you don't need to put async/await on it.

Change to

```
export default {
    getData(){
        return fetch(url+"campground")
        .then(result => result.json())
    }
}
```

Then because its return value is a promise, you need to await it (as others have said)

```
async created() {
  try {
    this.camps = await api.getData() 
  } catch {
    this.camps = []
  }
},
```

or

```
created() {
  api.getData().then(result => this.camps = result).catch(e => this.camps = [])
},
```

btw, if `camps` ends up as an array from the result you should define it as an empty array in data not `null`.

Comment: I'll ignore `url` not being defined

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked! I need to return the fetch like you said.

Comment: np, glad it helped